# phpunit passes all tests individually, but fails silently when running all

Tags: phpunit

I am just starting to get phpunit testing setup for a rather large legacy project that I'm working on. So far, I have two test files with three or four tests in each. When I run each file on it's own, all the tests pass, but when I run both of them in the directory, phpunit just fails silently. I suppose it doesn't matter in the big picture as long as I can run them individually, but does anyone have any idea why this is happening?